# Can I use multiple tailwind configured prefixes in 1 application?

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I am working on an application where the main package's tailwind.config.js has the prefix set.
eg
tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  prefix: 'my-prefix-',
}
```

However, I need to import components from another package that uses tailwind classes without a prefix.

Currently when importing components from the other package, none of the tailwind styles are applied as there is no prefix.

Is there a way to import components from the other package and have them work in the main application despite their different tailwind prefixes?

Comment: No you can't but you may try to use different entry points in your bundler or whatever tool you use. My point is to create two separate CSS files

Comment: The package you are importing should be also exporting a bundled css file. It's likely at '@package/dist/main.css'.